# Javascript string array to object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

How do I convert a string array:

```
var names = [
    "Bob",
    "Michael",
    "Lanny"
];
```

into an object like this?

```
var names = [
    {name:"Bob"},
    {name:"Michael"},
    {name:"Lanny"}
];
```

Comment: Where did "Saab" come from?

Comment: You might loop over the array and assign new values to elements like `names[i] = {name: names[i]}`.

Comment: @PeterB Thanks for finding the duplicate. Adding it to _"the list"_ :)

Comment: @Phil—not me, I just seconded Peter B's dupe.

Comment: @Phil right, there's no "Saab", sorry, I fixed that

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Super simple [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) job

```
names.map(name => ({ name }))
```

That is... map each entry (`name`) to an object with key "name" and value `name`.

```js
var names = [
    "Bob",
    "Michael",
    "Lanny"
];

console.info(names.map(name => ({ name })))
```

---

Silly me, I forgot the most important part

```
names.map(name => name === 'Bob' ? 'Saab' : name)
     .map(name => ({ name }))
```

Comment: Haha thanks, Phil :) That "Saab" was a spelling mistake, but I loved that you related to it and gave an answer to that too.

Answer (score 4):

Use the Array.map() function to map the array to objects.  The map() function will iterate through the array and return a new array holding the result of executing the function on each element in the original array.  Eg:

```
names = names.map(function(ele){return {"name":ele}});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this too:

```
var names = [
"Bob",
"Michael",
"Lanny"
];

var objNames = []

names.forEach(name => {
  objNames.push({
    name
  })
})
```

Using ES6 you can set `name` and it is equal to `name: name`

Answer (score 2):

you can use the map function. 
In general, list.map(f) will produce a new list where each element at position i is the result of applying f to the element at the same position in the original list.
For example:

```
names.map(function(s) { 
    return {name: s}
});
```